# Python Discord Bot and JS custom google browser

Tags: javascript, python, youtube, discord

i am new here and i wanted to create a custom Discord Bot. Starting with python, i was trying to implement a youtube searching feature to it, but i got locked away because of some user agent problem that looks overcomplicated for me, so i went to Developers.Google and i proceeded to create myself a custom search engine supposed to work with Youtube since i already had the API of it, but i realised that the code for it was in JS, thus making me ask the question : **is it possible to make this custom search engine work with my Python Bot ?**

here is my current code for it :

```py
import urllib.parse, urllib.request, re
import aiohttp
import asyncio
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def get_service():
    return build("youtube", "v3", developerKey="edmond-dantefesses")
def search(term, channel):
    service = get_service()
    resp = service.search().list(
        part="id",
        q=term,
        # safeSearch="none" if channel.is_nsfw() else "moderate",
        videoDimension="2d",
    ).execute()
    return resp["items"][0]["id"]["videoId"]

BASE = "https://youtube.com/results"

@bot.command()
async def YT(ctx, *, search):
    p = {"search_query": search}
    # Spoof a user agent header or the request will immediately fail
    h = {"User-Agent": "Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as bot:
        async with bot.get(BASE, params=p, headers=h) as resp:
            dom = await resp.text()
            # open("debug.html", "w").write(dom)
    found = re.findall(r'href"\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11})', dom)
    return f"https://youtu.be/{found[0]}"
```

i understand if my question sounds stupid or surreal and i thank you very much for your patience, have a good day :)